# What are some workplace perks/benefits which don't cost the company anything?

Tags: benefits

My work is looking for some ideas of perks/benefits for employees that doesn't cost the company money. For example: flexible working hours, flexible lunch hours, working from home when possible etc.

Basically anything that might help raise morale in the workplace. The company is an office based company. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: VTC, this seems too close to a popularity poll for a Q&A site.

Comment: @Lilienthal can you suggest anywhere else to post it?

Comment: No sites on the network, perhaps something like reddit is a better fit for this. The scope of the question is reasonably limited but this will probably still devolve into one-line answers with the most popular on top instead of the best answer, which is why these types of questions are frowned upon.

Comment: "flexible working hours, flexible lunch hours, working from home when possible"  Sounds like a great list you have already.  But these may actually have cost implications for the company.

Comment: Flexible hours do have a cost - time lost waiting to communicate... Just because something doesn't have an immediate dollar value doesn't mean it doesn't have a cost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My work is looking for some ideas of perks/benefits for employees that doesn't cost the company money.

That's a great idea. The best answer I can give you is *ask your employees*. Only *they* know what would make them happy. Giving them something they did not ask for and instead ignoring what they really want is not going to raise morale.

Ask them, make a list, prioritize it, make it happen. If something is too costly, tell them.